# Compiling node that needs an external library

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am beginner in ROS Kinetic and I don't know how to compile node that needs an external library. Please help in sorting out this issue.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241807/compiling-node-that-needs-an-external-library/) by [SaurabhR](https://answers.ros.org/users/27662/saurabhr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As this is a general question, here is the general answer:

[How to add add system dependency](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html)

If you have a specific issue, please update your question.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0